# How to create Project Dependencies Diagram in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions, diagram

We can create Class Diagram in Microsoft Visual Studio which shows relation between classes.

Is it possible to create/draw/export Project Dependencies Diagram? Something that shows dependencies between projects in a diagram, not only a list.

Is there any extension for Visual Studio to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio Ultimate, you can use the Architecture Menu -> Generate Dependency Graph.

I don't know if it's available in downlevel skus.

Comment: apparently this feature is not available in the Professional edition. :(

Comment: NDepend is a third party alternative. I haven't looked at it in nearly a decade, but it's still around, so it can't be bad. :)